# Polar histogram - no errors but makes no sense

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, python-3.6, polar-coordinates

I don't get any erros but the histogram doesn't make sense. Bars aren't centered at all. Here it is:

[image: ![https://i.imgur.com/CYAWqOM.png]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnG6x.png)

Some time ago I was doing something similar but the histogram was almost corect. It has gotten worse since. Here it is:
[image: ![https://i.imgur.com/LEkRz27.png]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG2S3.png)

I've tried playing around with ''width'',''bottom'' andd ''align'' but that didn't solve anything.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

Theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0*np.pi, 12)
Dim = [2.31330, 2.32173, 2.32841, 2.32068, 2.31452, 2.30792, 2.31313, 2.31847, 2.31910, 2.31516, 2.30617, 2.30408]
width = (2*np.pi) / 13

ax1 = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
bars = ax1.bar(Theta, Dim, color='b', width=width, bottom = 0.0, edgecolor = 'k', align = 'edge')
ax1.set_ylim(2.31000, 2.33000)
ax1.set_yticks(np.linspace(2.31000, 2.33000, 5))
ax1.set_rlabel_position(180)
ax1.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax1.set_theta_direction(-1)

plt.show()
```

Basically I just need the bars to meet at 0.0 and look like bars, not this. Whatever this is.

Answer (score 1):

The graph does not start at 0, but the bars will; so they are cut off. You may let the bars start at the middle of the graph by setting the `bar`'s `bottom` argument.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0*np.pi, 12)
Dim = np.array([2.31330, 2.32173, 2.32841, 2.32068, 2.31452, 2.30792, 2.31313, 
                2.31847, 2.31910, 2.31516, 2.30617, 2.30408])
width = (2*np.pi) / 13
origin = 2.31

ax1 = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

bars = ax1.bar(Theta, Dim-origin, color='b', width=width, bottom = origin, 
               edgecolor = 'k', align = 'edge')
ax1.set_ylim(origin, 2.33000)
ax1.set_yticks(np.linspace(2.31000, 2.33000, 5))
ax1.set_rlabel_position(180)
ax1.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax1.set_theta_direction(-1)

plt.show()
```

[image]